# jqplot graphs are displayed on top of one another

Tags: php, jquery, graph, jqplot

I have a form that the user fills in to show a report and when submitted the report basically shows a table with whatever values from the database and each table has a graph below it.

So the problem is when the report contains many tables, all the graphs are on top of each other after the first table, and you can only see the last graph but I want each graph to be after its table.

It worked perfect when I was using phplot but I don't know what the problem is here.
I even added the word 'graph' between the div tags just to test so:

```
<div id="chart1">graph</div>
```

and I get the word 'graph' after each table but the actual graphs are all stuck in one place.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here's my code for making the graphs:

```
    < script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var line1 =  <  ? php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
         ?  >
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1],
            {
                title : 'Daily usage from <?php echo $dateStart;?> to <?php echo $dateEnd;?>',
                axesDefaults :
                {
                    pad : 0
                },
                axes :
                {
                    xaxis :
                    {
                        renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickInterval : '1 day',
                        tickOptions :
                        {
                            angle : -30,
                            fontsize : '6pt',
                            formatString : '%d'
                        }
                    }
                },
                cursor :
                {
                    show : true,
                    zoom : true,
                    showTooltip : false
                },
                highlighter :
                {
                    show : true,
                    sizeAjust : 7.5
                }
            }
            );

    }
    );
<  / script >
```

Comment: does the probably misspelt property `sizeAjust` in `highlighter` break your `ready`handler ? have a look at the console output of your browser.

Comment: I fixed the misspelling but unfortunately it didn't change anything...